# Reduction on the gpu

Tags: c++, beginner, cuda

This program adds together all elements in an array with the function `parallelReduce`. Includes testing on an initialization with all 1's and a calculation of the speed up. I only tried to optimize the kernel itself, not the data transfer by initializing on the GPU for example.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <assert.h>

// To make error checking easier
inline cudaError_t checkCuda(cudaError_t result)
{
    if (result != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUDA Runtime Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(result));
        assert(result == cudaSuccess);
    }
    return result;
}

/*
Parallel reduce helper function. When run
with n/2 threads, changes array a to a' such that
the sum of the first n elements of a is equal to 
the sum of the first \lceil n/2 \rceil elements of a'
*/
__global__ void reduce(int* a, int n)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    for (int j = i; j < n / 2; j += stride)
    {
        a[j] += a[n - 1 - j];
    }
}

/*
For an array a of length n, puts the sum of all elements in a[0]
*/
void parallelReduce(int* a, int n)
{
    // Get some information about the GPU
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
    int multiProcessors = prop.multiProcessorCount;

    // Repeatedly use the helper function reduce to condense
    // a to its first element
    while (n > 1) {
        int threadsPerBlock = 256;
        int numberOfBlocks = 32 * multiProcessors;
        reduce << <numberOfBlocks, threadsPerBlock >> > (a, n);
        checkCuda(cudaGetLastError());
        n = (n + n % 2) / 2; // Rounds n/2 up.
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Initialize vector with N 1's.
    int N = (2 << 27) + 1; // The array size gets too big before we would need a long or long long for N.
    size_t size = N * sizeof(int);
    int* h_a;
    checkCuda(cudaMallocHost(&h_a, size));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        h_a[i] = 1;
    }

    // Copy to device (can be done asynchronically to hide transfer time, but 
    // that messes up the timing of the kernel).
    int* d_a;
    checkCuda(cudaMalloc(&d_a, size));
    checkCuda(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // Calculate the sum sequentially and time it.
    auto tic = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int hostSolution = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hostSolution += h_a[i];
    }
    auto toc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(toc - tic).count();

    std::cout << "The sequential function says the answer is " << hostSolution << " this took " << duration
        << " ms." << std::endl;

    // Kernel computation
    tic = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parallelReduce(d_a, N);
    checkCuda(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    toc = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int parallelDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(toc - tic).count();

    // Copy result back to host
    int solution;
    checkCuda(cudaMemcpy(&solution, &d_a[0], sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // Print the parallel result and speed up:
    std::cout << "The parallel function says the answer is " << solution << " this took " << parallelDuration
        << " ms." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "This means we have achieved a speed up of " << duration / parallelDuration << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Lol that’s definitely not a beginner question:) I don’t know anything about CUDA so I’m I can’t answer your question. Maybe you should consider bountying if you want to draw more attention